# PHP "ping" To prevent webpage timeout

Tags: php

I am editing an existing webpage which takes an excel spreadsheet and stores it in a database.

When the spreadsheet is large the page will time-out as there is no contact between the webpage and the server in that time.

Is there a simple way to "ping" the webpage without affecting the content of the page?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to extend the execution time of PHP in the config?

Comment: Is it running out of time to display the spreadsheet?  That's a different issue entirely.  You have to change the ini time limit setting.

Comment: Suppose I don't have access to the config as it is shared server, or another arbitrary reason like that.

Comment: @ExplosionPills it doesn't actually display the spreadsheet, the webpage doesn't change while it is storing the spreadsheet in the db.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Also thanks for the affecting* edit, I have very bad judgement for when to use which

Answer (score 2):

If your PHP page is just timing out because it's exceeding the maximum execution time, you could try setting the maximum execution time for just that script by using `ini_set` at the top of the page:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "600");  // Now times out after 5 minutes
```

You could try adjusting that to suit your needs.

If the script is taking a **very** long time to finish, you may have no choice but to set up a queue of these files to process.  Your main PHP script then does nothing but inserts the files into this queue, which is then processed by a cron job later.  You could then just poll the results of that later.

Comment: The original author of the page put `set_time_limit(24000);` at the top, I'm not a PHP expert, does it have a similar effect?

Comment: @ElmsPlusPlus Similar enough, but not quite identical.  That's setting a time limit of 400 minutes, so the browser is probably giving up long before the script's time limit is reached.  If you're still running into problems with this timing out with such a long timeout, you may have no choice but to do your processing offline like I mention above.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but depends on you implementation. For example if you process the excel file row by row then, yeah, it can be done:

```
<?php

while($notDone) {
    $row = proccessExcelRow($excelFile);
            // echo javascript so your browser won't fill the page with empty markup
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"></script>'; 
            @flush(); @ob_flush();
}
```

But if the script takes longer than the maximum_execution_limit it is useless. no other way around it than to forward it to a specialized process in the background